# Index match formula matching within a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been tinkering with an index match formula for a set of data structured like so

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atgmb.png)

Currently my formula looks like this, but of course it's only matching against the one row.
`=INDEX(B7:F13,MATCH(H7,A7:A12,0),MATCH(I7,B1:F1,0)`

I'd like for the following formula to work as below and match against all of the header rows, but I don't believe match has this functionality. Lookup formulas are also restricted to either 1 row or 1 column.

`=INDEX(B7:F13,MATCH(H7,A7:A13,0),MATCH(I7,B1:F6,0)`

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: What about `=INDEX(FILTER(B$7:F$12,A$7:A$12=H7),SUM((B$1:F$6=I7)*COLUMN(B$1:F$6))-1)`

Comment: Will header values always be unique? how should duplicates be handled if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Return Range Column of Cell Where Value Was Found

In cell `J7` use the following array formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$F$6,$I7)=0,"",INDEX($B$7:$F$12,MATCH($H7,$A$7:$A$12,0),MIN(IF($B$1:$F$6=$I7,COLUMN($A:$E))))),"")
```

The title of this post is referring to this array formula:

```
=MIN(IF($B$1:$F$6=$I7,COLUMN($A:$E))
```

which returns the column number needed for the `INDEX` function.

**Where is the error when you need one?**

- There could be matches in several columns. The `MIN` formula returns the left-most (`MAX` instead would return the right-most) column of a match. If there is no match, the `MIN` formula 'kindly' returns `0`. Where is the error...?
- Luckily `=INDEX($B$7:$F$12,1,0)` will return a `#VALUE!` error. Or will it? Unfortunately, it won't because `=INDEX($B$7:$F$12,1,0)` entered as an array formula 'kindly' returns the first value, in this example, of the first row.
  Where is the error...?
- So I had to include the miserable `IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$F$6,$I7)=0,"",...)`.

Answer (score 0):

It `J7`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$7:$F$12,MATCH(H7,$A$7:$A$12,0),SUMPRODUCT(COLUMN($A$1:$E$1)*($B$1:$F$6=I7))),"")
```

[image]